# NoRouteToHostException: No route to host-error while Running Elasticsearch on a cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having the following configurations in the `elasticsearch.yml`-

**Server-1:-**

```
cluster.name: rhel
node.name: "node-1"
network.host: 172.23.83.12
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.23.96.25"]
node.data : true
node.master : true 
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

**Server-2:-**

```
cluster.name: rhel
node.name: "node-2"
network.host: 172.23.96.25
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.23.83.12"]
node.data : true
node.master : true 
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

I am getting the following error while running ES on a cluster having two nodes(RHEL systems),

```
[2016-06-23 12:13:43,031][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [node-1] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xb46e3320]], closing connection
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:152)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
            at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
            at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    ^C[2016-06-23 12:13:43,494][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] stopping ...
    [2016-06-23 12:13:43,507][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] stopped
    [2016-06-23 12:13:43,507][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] closing ...
    [2016-06-23 12:13:43,514][INFO ][node                     ] [node-1] closed
```

Comment: Can you ping one host from the other and vice versa?

Comment: Yes I had tried that and i was able to ping.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable firewall on both the machines, after that it worked fine.